# Using macbook pro as display for raspberry pi 2

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I just received a pi 2 with sd card preloaded with NOOBS. I also have an hdmi cable and wifi dongle for it.

I wanted to begin using the pi 2 but do not have a spare monitor to connect it to. I was hoping to be able to connect to my macbook pro (Late 2013 - hence has HDMI) either via HDMI or wifi or ssh so that I could essentially use the macbook's display and keyboard to utilize the pi 2. How is this done, suggestions, recommended way of doing it?
Thank you

Comment: You would probably be better off asking this at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that, for the first time, you will need to have a monitor, keyboard and mouse and a LAN connection in order to check everything is going fine.

After you set up everything, you can go on using SSH & SFTP. You should setup x11vnc and you can be really good without any peripheral after that, you will only a LAN connection. If you have a WiFi Dongle for the PI, you also can be unplugged from the Ethernet Cable.

If you want to try, just plug the RPi and try to make an SSH, by checking your LAN devices. If you can, then you dont need anything else.

Cheers...